# Don't start systemctl service, like Docker, unless a control file is present

Tags: docker, systemd

I want to set up the configuration for Docker as such that, on boot, it does not automatically start the containers.

I've read about disabling the service with systemctl, which would required enabling it manually on next boot.

That being said, I would prefer it if I could configure the systemd service for Docker to wait for the presence of a certain file, in a certain location.

Once the file appears, it can start. And then I just remove it again. This means not having to set the service to disabled every time and potentially entering the wrong command and shutting it back down.

I've google for this, but can't find it.

Things like `Wants=` and `Required=`  in the Unit file seem to only accept other services and not file locations.

How could this be done?

Comment: The most elegant solution depends on the nature of that file - Are you trying to delay docker startup until a certain *mount point* is setup? A *unix socket*? A *PID file* that still needs an appropriate unit file to be recognized?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [path unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) to monitor a filesystem path and start the corresponding service. You can create a `docker.path` unit to activate a corresponding `docker.service` unit. It might look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Docker when my file exists

[Path]
PathExists=/my/path

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I finally got around to trying this and it doesn't work. I've  put the condition on a simple file in my home directory. The file doesn't exist. Enabled and started the .path file. Rebooted and docker just started normally, despite the file not existing.

Comment: `ConditionPathExists=` in the service file does seem to work though.

Comment: @KdgDev The service will continue to start if you left it enabled.

Comment: Doesn't disabling a service mean it won't start on on boot? Which is what I want, **except** if the file isn't present.

Comment: @KdgDev It is the path unit that starts the service when the path meets the condition specified.